# How should I install Kali Linux on my Windows 10?

Tags: kali-linux, windows-10, docker, vmware, wsl

I'm using Windows 10. I found several ways to install Kali Linux on Win10:

- Install it on VMWare
- Install it on Docker
- Install it on Linux subsystem (WSL)

I might need to access some files in my physical computer so I'd prefer the Linux subsystem. Can you tell me the pros and cons of each method ??? Is there any possible security threat from them ?

Comment: In the current form I consider this question mostly off-topic since listing all pros and cons of various methods to install Kali in Windows is not a security question. For the small part of "Is there any possible security threat from them" you would first need to describe what your use case and actual security requirements and threats are, i.e. what should be protected in the first place from what (Windows from Kali, Kali from Windows, Kali from external hackers ...). So please reduce your question to the security aspect and add the necessary details.

Comment: You can also access files on your computer using docker and vmware - this use case is no justification for doing it via the WSL...